# New factor based on values of others in the R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, variables

I have two data frames. The first one contains these variables:

| hh_id | Sit_in | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 34 |
| 1 | 3 | 12 |
| 2 | 3 | 11 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 56 |
| 2 | 2 | 41 |

`hh_id` is a household id (individuals with the same `hh_id` are from the same household)
`Sit_in` (1 == dad, 2 == mum, 3 == child)

The second one contains these variables :

| hh_id | Number_of_children |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

As you can see a household with the id 1 has 1 child and the one with the id 2 have 2;

So I want to create a new variable to give each individual the number of children he/she charge of so my data will look like this

| hh_id | Sit_in | Age | nb_charge_of |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 34 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 12 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 11 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 56 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 41 | 2 |

I've tried this code but it gives false results

```
test1 <- test1 %>%
  mutate(nb_c = ifelse(test1$hh_id == test2$hh_id &
                        test1$Set_in == 1 | test1$Set_in == 2, 
                      test2$nb_child, 0))
```

Any ideas, please

Answer (score 0):

```
left_join(df1, df2, 'hh_id') %>%
  mutate(nb_charge_of = Number_of_children *(Sit_in<3),Number_of_children=NULL)

  hh_id Sit_in Age nb_charge_of
1     1      2  34            1
2     1      3  12            0
3     2      3  11            0
4     2      3   5            0
5     2      1  56            2
6     2      2  41            2
```